# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java, jpa

why java.lang.ClassCastException is triggered in my program ?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.App.Equip]

The query returns the list of checklists that are answered (found in the CheckLists calsse) and not yet answered by Equip object

-Here is the code:

```
import org.json.simple.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public JSONObject ListCheckListsNonETRepondu( long idEqp, long idmiss){

       Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT"
        + " checksl.id_check_lists as IdCheckLists,"
        + " checksl.titre_check as NomCheckLists,"
        + " checksl.recommendation as Recommendation, "
        + " resp.id_responsescheck as IdResponse, "
        + " resp.conformite as Conformite, "
        + " resp.date_response as DateResponse, "
        + " resp.missions_id as IdMission "
        + " FROM equipements eq "
        + " LEFT JOIN check_lists checksl"
        + " ON eq.id_equipements= checksl.equipements_id "
        + " LEFT JOIN responses_check_lists resp "
        + " ON checksl.id_check_lists = resp.check_lists_id "
        + " AND resp.missions_id ="+idmiss+""
        + " AND eq.id_equipements ="+idEqp
        + " ORDER BY checksl.id_check_lists"
         );

   List<Equip> res = query.getResultList();

   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

   for( Equip eq: res) //--The problem is here --
   {
       for(CheckLists checks : eq.getChecks())
       {
              obj.put("idCheckLists", checks.getIdCheckLists());
              obj.put("NomCheckLists", checks.getTitreCheck());
              obj.put("Recommendation", checks.getRecommendation());

              for(ResponsesCheckLists resp :checks.getResponsesChecks())
               {
                  obj.put("IdResponse",resp.getIdResponsesCHeck());
                  obj.put("DateResponse",resp.getDateResponse());
                  obj.put("Conformite",resp.isConformite());
                  obj.put("IdMission",resp.getRespmission().getIdMission());
               }
       }

   }
   return (JSONObject)obj; 
   }
```

-My java classes:

```
@Entity
public class CheckLists implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idCheckLists")
    private long idCheckLists;

    @Column(name="titreCheck")
    private String titreCheck;

    @Column(name="recommendation")
    private String recommendation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="equipements_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Equipements equipements;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="CheckLts", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    //@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<ResponsesCheckLists> ResponsesChecks;
 ..
}

//
@Entity
public class ResponsesCheckLists implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idResponsesCHeck")
    private long idResponsesCHeck;

    @Column(name="conformite")
    private boolean conformite;

    @Column(name="dateResponse")
    private String dateResponse;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="missionsId")
    private Missions Respmission;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="checkLists_Id")
    private CheckLists CheckLts;

....
}

//
@Entity
public class Equip implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idEquipements")
    private long idEquipements;

    @Column(name="nomEq")
    private String nomEq;

    @Column(name="dateAjoutEq")
    private String dateAjoutEq;

    @Column(name="dateModificationEq")
    private String dateModificationEq;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="equipements", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    //@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<CheckLists> checks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="actifs_id")
    private Actifs actifsEquipements;
}
```

I want to format the result of my SQl query in Json format. 
Here is what the SQL query returns `query.getResultList()`:

```
[
   [
    1,
   "2.1 Create Separate Partition ",
   "Description.... ",
    1,
    false,
   "25/05/2017",
    15
  ],
  [
    2,
   "2.2 Set nodev option ",
  " Description:.... ",
    1,
    false,
   "25/05/2017",
   15
   ]
......
]
```

could anyone mind giving some advice for me?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: At which line this exception is thrown?

Comment: What is Equip? What is Query? are you using some library? The main problem is, probably, that the list returned by `query.getResultList();` has pure Object elements which cannot be cast to Equip, a reference to the classes you are using is necessary to understand the real problem.

Comment: In this line   `for( Equip eq: res) //--The problem is here -- `

Comment: Your query is returning an Object. Use the createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass) method with a class parameter, eg `createNativeQuery(sql, Equip.class)`. This might not work if query return column names don't map to the entity class.

Comment: @bracco23 I updated the post, thanks

Comment: I tried as you said @Jure Kolenko and I have this problem :  `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id_equipements' not found.`

Comment: How to view the JPA API version? @Mike Adamenko

Comment: jpa version must be in the name of jpa jar. try to use SqlResultSetMapping

Comment: OK @Mike Adamenko ,I will try now,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query is returning a `List` of `Object[]` because you aren't selecting an `Equip` Entity, but you are only selecting columns in :

```
   Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT"
    + " checksl.id_check_lists as IdCheckLists,"
    + " checksl.titre_check as NomCheckLists,"
    + " checksl.recommendation as Recommendation, "
    + " resp.id_responsescheck as IdResponse, "
    + " resp.conformite as Conformite, "
    + " resp.date_response as DateResponse, "
    + " resp.missions_id as IdMission "
```

Hibernate won't convert the `ResultSet` results to an `Equip` entity object, the result will be an array of `object`s because Hibernate won't determine the types of selected columns.

You need to loop over this `List` elements and transform each `Object[]` to an `Equip` object manually.

**Edit:**

This is how you should implement it:

```
List<Object[]> res = query.getResultList();
List<Equip> list= new ArrayList<Equip>();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

Iterator it = res.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
     Object[] line = it.next();
     Equip eq = new Equip();
     eq.setIdEquipement(line[0]);
     eq.setTitre(line[1]);
     eq.setDescription(line[2]);
     //And set all the Equip fields here
     //And last thing add it to the list

     list.add(eq);
}
```

Comment: How to get the text in Object [] and display it like this  `{
"idEquipement":"1",
"titre":2.1 Create Separate Partition ,
"description":"Description: ......",
}`

Comment: You need to lop over this array of objects.

Comment: how @chsdk,? I am a beginner in java

Comment: @Michel Check my eDit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ chsdk , i will test now

Answer (score 2):

My problem is solved through the use of the List: using the following code:

```
List<Object[]> res = query.getResultList(); 
List<Equip> list= new ArrayList<Equip>(); 

Iterator it = res.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
     Object[] line = it.next();
     Equip eq = new Equip();
     eq.setIdEquipement(line[0]);
     eq.setTitre(line[1]);
     eq.setDescription(line[2]);

     list.add(eq);
}
```

We return afterwards `list`

Answer (score 0):

`query.getResultList()` returns `List<Object[]>`

So you can either use JPA query to return `List<Equip>` or

**From JPA 2.0**

use mapped entities (as Jure Kolenko said)

```
createNativeQuery(sql, Equip.class)
```

**From JPA 2.1**

If you want map your result to POJO class use [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

> Example:
>
> ```
> Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
>     "SELECT o.id AS order_id, " +
>         "o.quantity AS order_quantity, " +
>         "o.item AS order_item, " +
>         "i.name AS item_name, " +
>     "FROM Order o, Item i " +
>     "WHERE (order_quantity > 25) AND (order_item = i.id)",
> "OrderResults");
>
> @SqlResultSetMapping(name="OrderResults", 
>     entities={ 
>         @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class, fields={
>             @FieldResult(name="id", column="order_id"),
>             @FieldResult(name="quantity", column="order_quantity"), 
>             @FieldResult(name="item", column="order_item")})},
>     columns={
>         @ColumnResult(name="item_name")}
> )
> ```

`@FieldResult` is the field from your Entity class

`@ColumnResult` is the result column from your ResultList that not exist into the your Entity class

See complete example [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-mapping-query-native.html)

Comment: I did not understand what this line is:  `@ColumnResult(name="item_name")}`  @Mike Adamenko

Comment: @MikeAdamenko isn't it only copy paste from this url  -- >> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ColumnResult.html

Need to delete this..

Comment: @VikrantKashyap this example is rather copied from url link `SqlResultSetMapping` right above the example

Comment: complete example here link is broken