# Spring Boot Repository - load DTO's direct from the Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

In my application I use DTOs. My current solution in pseudocode is this - works well:

```
ResponseEntity<EntityDTO> RestController.get(String uuid){
    EntityDTO dto = Service.get(uuid) {
         Entity entity = Repository.loadEntity(id);
         return EntityDTO.from(entity);
    }
    return ResponseEntity<EntityDTO>( dto , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Recently I saw an other solution without the transformation step in the service layer.

E.g. your Entity looks like this
:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
     Long id;
     String title;
     String text;
     .....
}
```

And the text is too 'heavy' to send it with the hole book you usually would create a DTO like this:

```
public class SlimBookDTO {,
     static SlimBookDTO from(Book book) {
           return new SlimBookDTO(book.id, book.title);
     }
     Long id;
     String title;
     .....
}
```

The "new" (for me) Solution is to create only an interface like this:

```
public interface SlimBookDTO {
    Long getId();
    String getTitle();
}
```

And your BookRepository gets a new method:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book , Long> {

    List<SlimBookDTO> findAllByTitle(String title);
}
```

With this method I don't need the service layer any more for direct requests. Is this common? Does somebody has experience with this? Has it some downsides that I can't see in a small application but will face in larger scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are couple of ways of returning data from the database.

1. You create DTO and map necessary fields and return
2. Other is create an interface which is directly a kind of return type from Repository. this is what we call as JPA interface projection.

For second one, you know in detail by referring below link
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

JPA interface projections are very useful when we query two or more entities in the Repository class

Comment: Great link! 5. Dynamic Projections is the answer for the question how I can choose between the DTO and the real object without two methods for it.

Comment: Have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176316/spring-data-when-use-projection-interfaces-and-dto-projections

Answer (score 2):

This is totally fine for simple GETs if the objects are straightforward enough, although of course you can't add additional logic, formatting or constraints. But as long as you don't need to do that, this will work well.

I don't think Hibernate analyzes the dto to only select a few fields though, so if you want to improve the performance too you can define the queries yourself, i.e. `@Query("select new com.bla.SlimbookDTO(book.id, book.title) from Book book")`, at the cost of not being able to just use automagically generated queries anymore based on the method name.

Comment: this would be in my case a relay high cost in terms of afford. My application is a tiny one but if it grows it is something useful to have in mind. Thanks