# Hibernate retrieve multiple rows and store in an object array

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to retrieve multiple rows of students from the database and then store them in a list of Student Objects. My Code is as follows

```
Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE class=:clsid";
SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("clsid", clsid);
List<Students> stdnts= new ArrayList<Students>();
stdnts = query.list();
System.out.println("First name "+stdnts.get(0).getName());
```

This throws an error and did not print the value of the name variable.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.test.stuff.model.Students

from the line

> System.out.println("First name "+stdnts.get(0).getName());

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassCastException: \[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285188/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Monty**
put addEntity method before list method like
          stdnts = query.addEntity(Students.class).list();
then it dont throw classCast exception.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks