# How to solve issue of "cannot cast object" for Microsoft SQL in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to call a stored procedure for my application using Microsoft SQL. However, when I run the stored procedure to pass back the contents of the object it fails. I have the objects as `AVSApplication` and in that class it has a list of variables and methods. I tried using an `Iterable` and a `List` but both produce the same error. I am not sure where I went wrong. I looked at other similar StackOverflow questions but I didn't get much from it.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.Mapping.AVSApplication
    at com.Mapping.Employeecontroller.getAll(Employeecontroller.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~
```

**Java Entity Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value= {
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name= "procedure-one", procedureName= "GetAllAppWithStatus")
})


public class AVSApplication implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String appcode;

    private String acronym;

    private String appname;

    private String sys_id;

    private String mapstatus;

    private String sdg;

    private String status;

    private String statuscode;



    //Constructor
    public AVSApplication(String appcode, String acronym, String appname, String sys_id, String mapstatus,
            String sdg, String status, String statuscode) {
        super();
        this.appcode = appcode;
        this.acronym = acronym;
        this.appname = appname;
        this.sys_id = sys_id;
        this.mapstatus = mapstatus;
        this.sdg = sdg;
        this.status = status;
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }




    //Getters

    public String getAppcode() {
        return appcode;
    }

    public String getAcronym() {
        return acronym;
    }

    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    public String getSys_id() {
        return sys_id;
    }

    public String getMapstatus() {
        return mapstatus;
    }

    public String getSdg() {
        return sdg;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getStatuscode() {
        return statuscode;
    }




    //Setters

    public void setAppcode(String appcode) {
        this.appcode = appcode;
    }

    public void setAcronym(String acronym) {
        this.acronym = acronym;
    }

    public void setAppname(String appname) {
        this.appname = appname;
    }

    public void setSys_id(String sys_id) {
        this.sys_id = sys_id;
    }

    public void setMapstatus(String mapstatus) {
        this.mapstatus = mapstatus;
    }

    public void setSdg(String sdg) {
        this.sdg = sdg;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setStatuscode(String statuscode) {
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }


}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Repository
public class Employeedao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Method to fetch all employees from the db.
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<AVSApplication> getAllEmployees() {
        return em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("procedure-one").getResultList();
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
public class Employeecontroller {


   @Autowired
   Employeedao edao;



   /**
    * Method to fetch all employees from the db.
    * @return
    */
   @RequestMapping(value= "/getall")
   public void getAll() {
      System.out.println("All objects: " + edao.getAllEmployees());

      System.out.println("Get the first item in list: " + edao.getAllEmployees().get(0).getAppcode());




   }

}
```

Comment: `AVSApplication` or `AQSApplication`? Pleasse be precise!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Its AVSApplication I just made a mistake in writing it to stack overflow.

Comment: Now the error message does not fit to the classes! You are obviously not showing the exact code that you are running! Please do not enter the code manually, but copy-paste the code and the error message. That way you make sure, it fits.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It should ,I am only using one class called ```AVSApplication```. I posted all of my code.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose From the error it looks like it is from the call to ```getAll()``` method in my controller.

Comment: The error also was about `AQSApplication`! You now also edited that a second time. After so much editing and mistakes, I doubt that this is the error you actually get. Please start with a new project and make a [mcve].

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, I had made a mistake. It should be ```AVSApplication``` NOT ```AQSApplication```.

Comment: this is what you might need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285188/java-lang-classcastexception-ljava-lang-object-cannot-be-cast-to

Answer (score 0):

In given code there is nothing that would map rows returned by stored procedure AVSApplication instances:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value= {
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name= "procedure-one", procedureName= "GetAllAppWithStatus")
})
```

If stored procedure matches nicely to entity, then definining result class can be enough:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(value= {
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name= "procedure-one", 
        procedureName= "GetAllAppWithStatus", 
        resultClasses = {AVSApplication.class}
})
```

If there is some discrepancies, one must define [SqlResultSetMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) and refer to it from [resultsetMappings](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.html#resultSetMappings--).